# When subscribing charge automatically and get error if there are not enough funds

Tags: stripe-payments, payment

To solve the problem to charge automatically on subscriptions I used these two properties when creating a subscription:

```
**collection_method**: 'charge_automatically',
**billing_cycle_anchor**: 'now'.
```

Now the problem is that I want to get an error immediately when there are not enough funds to charge, but the only way that I came around to get the error is using a webhook to get **invoice.payment_failed**. But this is not solving my problem.

Is there any way to get the error after subscribing or creating the payment method?

Comment: Setting payment_behavior to default_incomplete or similar might be what you're looking for: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/overview#:~:text=CREATING%20INCOMPLETE%20SUBSCRIPTIONS (Section "CREATING INCOMPLETE SUBSCRIPTIONS" on the right)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you may want to [set `payment_behavior` to `error_if_incomplete` when creating the Subscription](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create#create_subscription-payment_behavior).

> Use `error_if_incomplete` if you want Stripe to return an HTTP 402 status code if a subscription’s first invoice cannot be paid. For example, if a payment method requires 3DS authentication due to SCA regulation and further user action is needed, this parameter does not create a subscription and returns an error instead. This was the default behavior for API versions prior to 2019-03-14. See the [changelog](https://stripe.com/docs/upgrades#2019-03-14) to learn more.

Note the warning about 3D Secure and SCA though!

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for!